# 554 message rejected email address is not verified. amazon ses-java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have been verified both from and to email addresses(both the emails are case sensitive) over and over
and I still get the 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified Rejection from SES. But when i try to send the emails from Amazon SES Console by using the same email, it is working fine. If my from and to emails not been verified then from console also it should nt work. Not able to understand what is going on.

```
public class AmazonSESSample {

    static final String FROM = "from email";
    static final String TO = "to email";

    static final String BODY = "This email was sent through the Amazon SES SMTP interface by using Java.";
    static final String SUBJECT = "Amazon SES test (SMTP interface accessed using Java)";

    // Supply your SMTP credentials below. Note that your SMTP credentials are different from your AWS credentials.
    static final String SMTP_USERNAME = "SMTP USER NAME";
    static final String SMTP_PASSWORD = "SMTP PWD";

    static final String HOST = "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";    

    // Port we will connect to on the Amazon SES SMTP endpoint. We are choosing  port 25 because we will use
    // STARTTLS to encrypt the connection.
    static final int PORT = 25;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Create a Properties object to contain connection configuration information.
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", PORT); 

        // Set properties indicating that we want to use STARTTLS to encrypt the connection.
        // The SMTP session will begin on an unencrypted connection, and then the client
        // will issue a STARTTLS command to upgrade to an encrypted connection.
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");

        // Create a Session object to represent a mail session with the specified properties. 
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

        // Create a message with the specified information. 
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM));
        msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(TO));
        msg.setSubject(SUBJECT);
        msg.setContent(BODY,"text/plain");

        // Create a transport.        
        Transport transport = session.getTransport();

        // Send the message.
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Attempting to send an email through the Amazon SES SMTP interface...");

            // Connect to Amazon SES using the SMTP username and password you specified above.
            transport.connect(HOST, SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);

            // Send the email.
            transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
            System.out.println("Email sent!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("The email was not sent.");
            System.out.println("Error message: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close and terminate the connection.
            transport.close();          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: we are facing same problem.Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and it turned out to be a simple blind copy-paste issue. Currently, there are 3 regions with SES. Depending on which region you setup the ID, the HOST variable has to be modified accordingly.

```
static final String HOST = "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
```

That fixed my problem. Afterwards, if you want to send emails to unverified email addresses, you have to move your setup out of the sandbox.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html

Answer (score 1):

Is this the first time you are using this account with SES? If so then you must be in sandbox mode

If your account is still in the sandbox, you also must verify every recipient email address except for the recipients provided by the Amazon SES mailbox simulator.

[SES Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/troubleshoot-error-messages.html)

You can follow these steps :

1 Log into the AWS Management Console.

2 Go to SES Sending Limits Increase.

3 Fill in the required details and set the limit to your desired usage

[Moving Out of Sandbox](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html)